# Spring Boot the property spring.jpa.show-sql doesn't work with Datastore

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I am using Springboot with Datastore.
Do you know the configuration that is needed to view the sql query when we make a call to datastore ? Something like spring.jpa.show-sql = true
Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such configuration in Spring Boot. But as an alternative you try to enable the [Datastore audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/audit-logging). The audit logs will contain the information about all the operations that are performed in your Cloud Datastore database, including the queries that are executed.

Then you can [route the audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/audit-logging#exporting_audit_logs) to Cloud Storage, BigQuery, or Pub/Sub, to other applications, other repositories, and to third parties.